# Do I need a Panama transit visa with a Zimbabwean passport to the Bahamas

Tags: air-travel, transit-visas, panama, bahamas, zimbabwean-citizens

I have a Zimbabwean passport traveling from Johannesburg to the Bahamas, do I need a visa to transit through Panama City?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on layover time, no, according to TIMATIC :

> Visa required.
> Visa Exemptions:
> Nationals of Zimbabwe with a multiple entry visa issued by Australia, Canada, Japan, Korea (Rep.), Singapore, USA or an EU Member state . The visa must have been used and be valid for a minimum of 6 months on arrival. Passengers must travel as tourists for a maximum stay of 90 days.
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

No Visa is necessary if you book your entire trip on a **single** ticket, if   it isn't the case, you will need to get a visa beforehand